# SQL group by problem

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have a query which does a number of joins and has a few criteria in the WHERE clause, and I'm ending up with a result which essentially looks like this:

```
| userId |       date |  otherData |
|--------+------------+------------|
|      1 | 2008-01-01 |  different |
|      1 | 2009-01-01 |       info |
|      1 | 2010-01-01 |        for |
|      2 | 2008-01-01 |       each |
|      3 | 2008-01-01 |        row |
|      3 | 2009-01-01 |       here |
```

So, in essence for each user, there will be one or more dates in the past, and 0 or more dates in the future.

I need to somehow reduce the dataset to one row per user, **only selecting the row which has the most recently passed date**. That is, with whatever magic `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause is added, the result from above would look like this:

```
| userId |       date |  otherData |
|--------+------------+------------|
|      1 | 2009-01-01 |       info |
|      2 | 2008-01-01 |       each |
|      3 | 2009-01-01 |       here |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't want to use GROUP BY / HAVING because you are interested in exactly 1 row per user, and that row already exists in the table as-is. This calls for a WHERE clause and not GROUP BY / HAVING.

My suggestion is that in the WHERE clause, you add a condition that the date must be equal to the result of a subquery. That subquery should:

1. Select the max(date)
2. Have a WHERE clause that limits date to be smaller than NOW
3. Have a WHERE clause with UserID equals outer query's user id

To prevent cases where a certain user can have two entries with the same date that's also the maximum "passed" date, you should also add DISTINCT.

Hope that helps.

Comment: works fine!! but adding DISTINCT not removing duplicate values, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
select a.userId, a.date, b.userId, b.otherData
from table1 as a 
left outer join table2 as b on a.userId = b.userId
where b.Id in (
    select top 1 Id from table2 as c where c.userId = a.userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  userID, date, otherData 
from 
  yourTable t1
where 
  date = 
    (select max(date) from yourTable t2
     where t1.userID=t2.userID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T.userid, T.date, T.otherdata 
from 
    T, 
    (select userid, max(date) max_date from T group by userid) GT
where 
    T.userid = GT.userid and T.date = GT.max_date
```

Explanation:
Inner select - izolate only the records with the max date for each user.
entire select - join izolated records with the original table, to get the otherdata field.

I assumed that there is only one max date for a user id. Please say if it is the correct assumption.